# is it safe to apply double-checked locking to Dictionary?

Tags: c#

Is it safe to apply double-checked locking to `Dictionary`?

I.e. if it safe to call `TryGetValue` and other "get/contains" methods from different threads? (without calling other, non-get methods).

**upd** Would collection be safe for N readers AND 1 writer? Assume In cycle 10 threads are try to access element with key X using double-checked locking and if accessed they just remove it. At some point I do add element with key X from one another thread (using lock). I expect that exactly one reader should obtain this element and delete it.

**upd2, about answer** so my question is confusing. actually I've asked two questions:

1. if it safe to call `TryGetValue` and other "get/contains" methods from different threads? (without calling other, non-get methods).
2. Would collection be safe for N readers AND 1 writer?

The answer for first question is Yes and the answer for second question is No.

So sometimes it's safe to `apply double-checked locking` sometimes it is not. It depends on if you are writing at the same time to a collection.

Comment: According to the specs the anser is yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: I am not aware that you need locks for a data structure which is accessed as read only data structure aka immutable type which is inherently thread safe. If you never change it there is no need for a lock at all.

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.0 or higher you can use for this ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: @AloisKraus point of using double-checked locking is not to use lock when not required to win several nanoseconds and i do need them as i'm writing HFT.

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary is a nearly lock free data structure. Under the hood it does use a similar pattern to enable updates nearly lock free.

Comment: @AloisKraus do you think `ConcurrentDictionary` would be faster than `Dictonary + own lock`? do you have links or something?

Comment: There is a very good paper online called Thread-safe Collections in .NET Framework 4 - Microsoft ( see http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FB%2FC%2FF%2FBCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D%2FPerformanceCharacteristicsOfThreadSafeCollection.pdf&ei=RHvfUMebLKWo4ASL94CAAQ&usg=AFQjCNFiqwg34_7Du233kJjkZRBTVzWDBg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bGE&cad=rja ). The paper does describe it in much greater detail. It depends how the ratio of readers vs. writers if you see a perf gain by using ConcurrentDictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class. That class is safe for N readers or 1 writer. So as long as you're not modifying it, you can have as many threads you want reading from it, no lock required.

If it's possible that a thread will want to modify the dictionary, you have to synchronize access to it. I would suggest [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

Comment: thanks, why using `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead of general `lock`? would it be faster?

Comment: I really disagree that it is safe to do this. See my answer.

Comment: @javapowered because it is optimized for the case where writers need an exclusive lock, but readers do not.  A simple lock implementation doesn't allow concurrent readers.

Comment: @usr This answer says you can have one writer *or* multiple readers, not "and", and the documentation *does* support that assertion.

Comment: @Jim Mischel I misread the answer. I must be edited so I'll be able to revert the downvote. I'll check tomorrow if I can revert it.

Comment: @phoog, the docs do not support one writer *and* >=1 readers. They support "xor".

Answer (score 1):

This is not safe because it is not documented to be safe. You can't have one writer and N readers.

Here is an applicable sentence from the docs:

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   as long as the collection is not modified.

Actually, if you peek into Dictionary with Reflector you can see that it is unsafe, but that is not the point. The point is that you cannot rely on undocumented properties because they can change at any time, introducing bugs into production that nobody knows about.

You also cannot test this to be safe. It might work on your box and break somewhere else. This is the nature of threading bugs. Not worth it.

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation? "A Dictionary<TKey, TValue> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified."

Comment: @phoog, multiple readers but not with a concurrent writer at the same time. That's a difference.

Comment: yes, I see -- I read your answer in relation to Jim Mischel's answer, not in relation to the question, since I had read his answer more recently than the question.  If you edit your answer I will be able to remove my down vote.

Comment: @phoog edited. I've cause quite some confusion misreading that single word.